# Instagram and Image Size

Tags: nikon, lightroom, photoshop, instagram

I shoot a Nikon D750. In a image size Large. I know Instagram has limitations, but what are they. Should I shoot in Image size Large, Medium, or Small? Or shoot size Large, then adjust in Lightroom or Photoshop? If so, how, where? Thanks so so much.

Comment: What is the purpose of the link as it relates to this question?

Answer (score 2):

Maximums from http://colorlib.com/wp/size-of-the-instagram-picture/

```
Square Image: 1080px in width by 1080px in height

Vertical Image:  1080px in width by 1350px in height

Horizontal Image: 1080px in width by 566px in height
```

Not said as clearly, but verified at 
http://help.instagram.com/1631821640426723

D750 Small image is

FX  3008 x 2008
DX  1968 x 1312

How? Google Lightroom resample

One result is http://photographylife.com/how-to-properly-resize-images-in-lightroom

Or Photoshop resample

One is
http://www.photoshopessentials.com/essentials/resizing-vs-resampling/